# How to display parsed json using linked array lists, custom handler, nested classes and onSuccess instead of onPostExecute method

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-asynctask, string-parsing

I'm unable to convert parsed Json data to strings and display.

I'm attempting to display the json in String format from within an inner class of the Main activity, which uses an arraylist as a name as-well as using a handler, the inner class of the main activity is called: 
**MovesHandler**

```
   private MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>> storylineHandler = new MovesHandler{
```

...
}

I'm attempting to uses the Main Activity's inner classes onSuccess method to display the json as Strings like this: 
**MovesHandler**

```
    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<StorylineData> result){
    updateResponse("Summary size : " + result.size() + "\n"
     + result.add(storylineData)+"\n"
     + storylineData.toString()"\n"
     + storylineData.getDate() + "\n"
     + storylineData.getSummary() + "\n"

        }
```

The MainActivity's inner class uses a handler interface class called 
**MovesHandler (Interface class):**

```
public interface MovesHandler<T> {  
...
}
```

I attempt to update the display like this: 
**MainActivity**

```
 public void updateResponse(final String message) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mEditTextResponse.setText(message);
}
```

The parsing code looks like this:
**StorylineData**

```
   public static StorylineData parse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                        StorylineData storylineData = new StorylineData();
                storylineData.date          = jsonObject.optString("date");
                        storylineData.caloriesIdle  = jsonObject.optString("caloriesIdle");
                        storylineData.lastUpdate    = jsonObject.optString("lastUpdate");
                        storylineData.summary       = new ArrayList<SummaryData>();
                        storylineData.segments      = new ArrayList<SegmentData>();
                    JSONArray summariesJsonArray= jsonObject.optJSONArray("summary");
                    if (summariesJsonArray != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < summariesJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject summaryJsonObject = summariesJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                            if (summaryJsonObject != null) {
                                storylineData.summary.add(SummaryData.parse(summaryJsonObject));
                            Log.d("storylineHandler", summaryJsonObject.toString());

                        }
                    }
                }
                JSONArray segmentsJsonArray= jsonObject.optJSONArray("segments");
                if (segmentsJsonArray != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < segmentsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject segment = segmentsJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                        if (segment != null) {
  storylineData.segments.add(SegmentData.parse(segment));


                            Log.d("storylineHandler", segment.toString());
    }
                    }
                }

                return storylineData;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The MovesApi method:   `public static void getStoryline_SingleDay(MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>> handler, String date, String updatedSince, boolean needTrackPoints)` that is executed inside a class called MovesAPI and called from the MainActivity's switch case:

```
case 10: // Get Storyline Day
            MovesAPI.getStoryline_SingleDay(storylineHandler, "20150418", null, false);
```

uses the MAinActivity's inner class named: `private MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>> storylineHandler = new MovesHandler`.

The MovesApi class looks like this:

**MovesAPI**

```
public class MovesAPI {
variables...

    public static void getStoryline_SingleDay(MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>> handler, String date, String updatedSince, boolean needTrackPoints) {
        if (AuthData.isAuthenticated()) {
            HTTPCall.getDailyStorylineList(handler, "/" + date, null, null, null, updatedSince, needTrackPoints);
        } else {
            handler.onFailure(MovesStatus.NOT_AUTHENTICATED, "You are not yet authenticated with required scopes!");
        }
    }
```

The response displayed is Null but raw json data appears in the log cat.

From my research I think I'm right in saying the data I'm trying to display consists of linked array lists, uses a custom handler and what seems to be a custom adapter or custom asyncTask?

Please bare in mind I'm new to Android so please provide help in laymen's terms as I'm a bit confused regarding adapters, asyncTask, JsonObjects, JsonArrays, linked array lists and if and how I could convert my code to use an onPost/pre execute method instead of onSuccess?

The MainActivity looks like this:
**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{
    ..other variables here..

    StorylineData storylineData;
    ArrayList<SummaryData> summaries;
    ArrayList<SegmentData> segments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
other ui elements here...
        mEditTextResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editResponse);
     MovesAPI.init(this, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, CLIENT_SCOPES.....

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        toggleProgress(true);
        switch (mSpinnerAPI.getSelectedItemPosition()) {

 other cases here...

                break;
    other cases here...

            case 4: // Get Summary Day
                MovesAPI.getSummary_SingleDay(summaryHandler, "20150418", null);//Date changed to "20150117"
                break;

  Other cases here..
            case 10: // Get Storyline Day
                MovesAPI.getStoryline_SingleDay(storylineHandler, "20150418", null, false);//Date changed to "20150418"
                break;

  Other cases here..
                break;
            case 16: // Get Activities Day
                MovesAPI.getActivities_SingleDay(storylineHandler, "20150418", null);//Date changed to "20150410"
                break;

  Other cases here..

        }

    }

...   Other MovesHandlers here...

    private MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>> storylineHandler = new MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>>() {
@Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<StorylineData> result) {

            toggleProgress(false);
                updateResponse("Summary size : " + result.size() + "\n" 

                        + result.add(storylineData)+"\n"

                        + storylineData.toString()+ storylineData.getDate() + "\n"
                           + storylineData.toString()+ storylineData.getSummary() + "\n"


                onFailure code here..

        }
    };

    public void toggleProgress(final boolean isProgrressing) {

     togglePregress code here..
    }

    public void updateResponse(final String message) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mEditTextResponse.setText(message);



            }
        });
    }
}
```

**HTTPCall**

```
 public static void getDailyStorylineList(final MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>> handler,
                                             final String specificSummary,
                                             final String from,
                                             final String to,
                                             final String pastDays,
                                             final String updatedSince,
                                             final boolean needTrackPoints) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    /* Refresh access token if only AuthData.MOVES_REFRESHBEFORE days are there to expire current token */
                    AuthData.refreshAccessTokenIfNeeded();

                    /* Exchange the authorization code we obtained after login to get access token */
                    HashMap<String, String> nameValuePairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    nameValuePairs.put("access_token", AuthData.getAuthData().getAccessToken());


                    if (from != null && from.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("from", from);
                    if (to != null && to.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("to", to);
                    if (pastDays != null && pastDays.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("pastDays", pastDays);
                    if (updatedSince != null && updatedSince.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("updatedSince", updatedSince);
                    if (needTrackPoints) nameValuePairs.put("trackPoints", "true");


                    URL url     = new URL(MovesAPI.API_BASE + MovesAPI.API_PATH_STORYLINE + (specificSummary != null ? specificSummary : "") + "?" + Utilities.encodeUrl(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                        /* All other HTTP errors from Moves will fall here */
                        handler.onFailure(getErrorStatus(Utilities.readStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream()), urlConnection.getResponseCode()), "Server not responded with success ("+ urlConnection.getResponseCode() +")");
                        return;
                    }

                    String response = Utilities.readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    Object object = new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                    if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) object;
                        ArrayList<StorylineData> storylineData = new ArrayList<StorylineData>();
                        if (jsonArray != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject storylineJsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                                if (storylineJsonObject != null) {
                                    storylineData.add(StorylineData.parse(storylineJsonObject));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        handler.onSuccess(storylineData);
                    } else {
                        handler.onFailure(MovesStatus.INVALID_RESPONSE, "Expected a JSONArray from server, but failed");;
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    handler.onFailure(MovesStatus.UNEXPECTED_ERROR, "An unexpected error occured, please check logcat");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: To improve this question, I suggest reducing the code only to the relevant parts. This question is difficult to answer if you paste all your code (which is very long).

Comment: Thanks icedtrees. I have reduced the code loads, but will try to reduce it some more & hopefully not leave out anything important to solving the problem, thanks again.

Comment: I have edited and reduced the code to only the relevant parts. Hopefully the question will now be easier to answer, thanks.

Comment: Step through with a debugger so you can get a sense at least of where it's starting to go wrong.

Comment: Where is `onSuccess` called?

Comment: Thanks for the input Soana, I have edited the question above to include the onSuccess code of the Main activity, hopefully it makes things clear? I assumed the onSuccess was executed during the method call: MovesAPI.getSummary_SingleDay(summaryHandler, "20150418", null); as that method utilises the main activity's inner class: MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>.

Comment: M best guess is that `updatedSince` may not be `null` and when it is, `onSuccess` is not called. Have you verified that `onSuccess` is actually called, e.g. via a log output?

Comment: Thanks for your input nasch, I will attempt stepping through the code with the debugger. I have also added the MovesAPI class to the code above. MovesAPI contains the method that uses the combined array list and handler as an inner class. I hope it makes the question clearer?

Comment: I have used Log.d("storylineHandler", summaryJsonObject.toString()); which shows the raw json in the log cat. I assumed that meant the onsuccess was called?

Comment: It is not in the `onSuccess`-method as far as I can see, so no, you can't be sure. Maybe there is some strange `if` in some method (like `HTTPCall.getDailyStorylineList`) where it should call `onSucess` but the condition is false.

Comment: Thanks Soana I've gone through the method `HTTPCall.getDailyStorylineList` & the HTTPCall Class to see if I can find a false value in the if statement, but I've had no luck. I've added the HTTPCall code above. Also the MainActivity's onSuccess method seems to be called because if I do `+ result.size() ` within MainActivity's  onSuccess method it returns as 1. However if I add `+ Log.d("storylineHandler", summaryJsonObject.toString())` to onSuccess you'r right, seems onSuccess is not called as I get `onFailure` message `UNEXPECTED_ERROR` from the HTTPCall class. I'm not sure what to do ? .

Comment: Is your problem maybe that the EditText displays the correct values once but never changes thereafter, even though new data becomes available?

Comment: Well I have tried displaying only the parsed data as a JsonObject & String using edit text just once & it still doesn't display the correct values, it just displays null wether new data or old. But parsed data from StorylineData parser class still appears in log cat when I use d.log...?

Comment: I think you problem is that you are referencing `sorylineData`in `onSuccess`, which is an attribute of `MainActivity`. This is never updated with the new data, thus the output will always be wrong. If this is the case then you might be seeing a `NullPointerException` in the log cat, depending on whether `storylineData` is ever set initially.

Comment: Thanks Soana, I think your right I do get a 'NullPointerException' as you described. The thing is I thought StorylineData was set & when I've attempted multiple ways to set it I still get a Null response in the display. I think it's because I'm new to coding & StorylineData uses another array/class. StorylineData is also an array, a class & becomes a JsonObject so I get confused as to how & if it's set initially. Can you tell from the StorlineData code if it's set initially? Alternatively please let me know how & where you would suggest it should be set initially?

Comment: Next time: if you see an exception, post the full log cat of the stacktrace and ideally indicate the line in the code, where the error occures according to the stacktrace.

Comment: Also ask a new question about this. It has very little to do with this question.